# How to make the delay when a user check on Vue.js?

Tags: ajax, vue.js, single-page-application, vue-resource, vue-router

I have SPA application on Vue.js + Laravel. Authorization logic, completely delegated to Laravel app. However, i need check auth status, when routing has changed. I create small class, which responsible for it.

```
export default {
user: {
    authenticated : false
},
check: function(context) {
    context.$http.get('/api/v1/user').then((response) => {
    if (response.body.user != null) {
      this.user.authenticated = true
    }
  }, (response) =>{
     console.log(response)
  });
}
```

Within the component has a method that is called when a change url.

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
next(vm =>{
  Auth.check(vm);
    if (!Auth.user.authenticated) {
      next({path:'/login'});
    }
})
}
```

Function `next()` given Vue app instance, then check user object. If user false, `next()` call again for redirect to login page.  All it works, but only when the page is already loaded. If i'll reload /account page, there is a redirect to /login page, because request to Api not completed yet, but code will continue execute. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Done. Need to return promise like that

```
check: function(context) {
 return context.$http.get('/api/v1/user').then((response) => {
  if (response.body.user != null) {
   this.user.authenticated = true
  }
}, (response) =>{
    console.log(response)
   });
}
```

and then

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
   Auth.check().then(()=>{
      if(!Auth.user.authenticated) 
        next({path:'/login'})
      else
        next();
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple to do, you need to make your code work asynchronously and hold routing before request is completed.

```
export default {
    user: {
        authenticated : false
    },
    check: function(context) {
        return context.$http.get('/api/v1/user').then((response) => {
            if (response.body.user != null) {
                this.user.authenticated = true
            }
        }, (response) => {
            console.log(response)
        });
    }
}
```

then

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
        Auth.check(vm).then(() => {
            if (!Auth.user.authenticated) {
                next({path:'/login'});
            } else {
                next()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Other pro tips

- Display some loading indicator when loading so your application doesn't seem to freeze (you can use global router hooks for that)
- If you are using vue-resource, consider using [interceptors](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md#interceptors) (perhaps in addition to the routing checks)
- Consider using `router.beforeEach` so that you don't have to copy-paste `beforeRouteEnter` to every component

Comment: Wow, this solution is exactly like my :D Thanks for answer and for tips

Comment: Congrats for figuring out proper solution yourself then ;)